# Getting Zeros When Reading A File Full of Numbers

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file that has several hundred lines. Each line looks roughly like this (Keep in mind these are not the actual numbers. Just a sample of the format.)
    R 111.1111 222.2222 123456 11 50.111 51.111

I tried reading this file with fscanf and then printing out some of the values but when I print out the values, I get 0 for all the variables. I have checked the file and none of the lines have a value of 0 for all the variables. I am writing in C++.

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
  FILE *myfile;
  myfile = fopen("tmp.txt", "r");

  string type;
  float dx;
  float dy;
  float intensity;
  int nsat;
  float rmsy;
  float rmsx;

  if (myfile == NULL) exit(1);

  else
    {
      while ( ! feof (myfile) )
       {
      fscanf(myfile,"%s %f %f %f %i %f %f\n",&type, &dx, &dy, &intensity, &nsat, &rmsx, &rmsy);
      printf("F %f %f %f %i %f %f\n", dx, dy, intensity, nsat, rmsx, rmsy);

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You question is tagged fstream/ifstream yet you're using FILE* ?

Comment: Yes. Is this not the appropriate type of file? I have little experience writing in C++.

Comment: To be fair even the C++ tag is wrong, you include C++ headers but your entire code relies on standard C library functions.

Comment: You also don't have a `#include` for `cstdio`...

Comment: And now your code won't even compile...

Comment: I never properly learned C/C++. I learned Java. And now have to write in C++ for work. Can I get more explanation on the above comments? Sorry, some errors happened in the copy/paste.

Comment: I'd recommend a C++ primer - just google around and you'll find plenty of results

Comment: I'm curious how this compiles in the first place. you have multiple statements between if and else but no braces. AFAIK this is not legal syntax.

Comment: I will look for a C++ solution to what I want to do. But can I get an explanation as to why this doesn't work? (I am assuming I fixed the syntax errors.) I want to learn more about C++.

Comment: The code is plain C if you replaced the first 3 lines with #include <stdio.h> and #include <stdlib.h>. There is no need to make this a C++ program if that's all you needed to do.

Comment: This is not the full program. Once this is working I will need to flesh it out using opencv libraries, which use c++.

Comment: Use `std::ifstream` instead of C's `fscanf` and `std::cout` instead of `printf`.

Comment: If I use std:ifstream read, is it possible to read the file integer by integer? I can only find examples to read line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code, but:

The problem is the `%s` at the beginning of the format string. `%s` matches the complete line and thus contains all values.

Perhaps you can use `%c` instead, if you are sure, there is only one char before the numbers.

Also notice that you passted a `std::string`-Pointer to `scanf`. This is invalid, since `scanf` needs a `char` buffer to store a string (`%s`) which is not a good idea at all, since you don't know the required length of the buffer.

This works for me:

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  FILE *myfile;
  myfile = fopen("tmp.txt", "r");

  char type;
  float dx;
  float dy;
  float intensity;
  int nsat;
  float rmsy;
  float rmsx;

  // The NULL-if should be here, but left out for shortness
  while ( ! feof (myfile) )
  {
    fscanf(myfile,"%c %f %f %f %i %f %f",&type, &dx, &dy, &intensity, &nsat, &rmsx, &rmsy);
    printf("F %f %f %f %i %f %f\n", dx, dy, intensity, nsat, rmsx, rmsy);
  }
}
```

Comment: Mmmm, I did not know that about %s. I made the change from %s to %c but it seems I'm still getting 0s.

Comment: Have you changed the `std::string`-thing?

Comment: Try to remove the `\n` at the end of the format string for `scanf`.

Comment: Solved! The problem was with %s and std::string. Thank for your constructive comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `std::ifstream`

note This code doest assume that the input file is always nicely formatted and no values are missing on one rule

```
#include <fstream> //for ifstream
#include <string> //for strings

ifstream stream ( "tmp.txt", ios::in );
string type;
float dx;
float dy;
float intensity;
int nsat;
float rmsy;
float rmsx;

while ( stream >> type){
    stream >> dx;
    stream >> dy;
    stream >> intensity;
    stream >> rmsy;
    stream >> rmsx;

    cout << type << '\t'
        << dx << '\t'
        << dy << '\t'
        << intensity <<'\t'
        << rmsy << '\t'
        << rmsx << endl;
}
```

and with input.txt =

```
 R 111.1111 222.2222 123456 11 50.111
 T 111.1111 222.2222 123456 11 50.111
```

this prints this out again, note this is more idiomatic C++.

output =

```
R   111.111 222.222 123456  11  50.111
T   111.111 222.222 123456  11  50.111
```